# iOS7 UISearchBar cancel button text not showing. Button appears invisible

Tags: ios, ios7, uisearchbar, uisearchbardelegate

I am hoping this is an easy question.

[image]

I have a search bar that shows a cancel button:

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
}
```

Only problem is that the text on the cancel button isn't showing.

[image]

The button is obviously there because I can click on it but no text appears when the button is shown. Its as if the button is invisible. The code worked fine in iOS6 but now in iOS7 I am having this problem.  Any body have any ideas? I am using a UISplitViewController and my search bar is in the navigationItem.titleView of the MasterViewController.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Probably You got clear tint color, it's the only reason I could imaging
try to set

`_searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];`

How do You create UISearchBar?

Comment: I thought that might be the issues but I tried different tint colors and also removing the tint completely and it didn't make a difference.  I create the search bar programatically. It's inserted into a UIView which is added to the  navigationItem.titleView of the MasterViewController.

Comment: I had an issue with my background image but this also helped.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if it is a bug from apple or intended but the cancel button doesn't appear to show while in a navigationController. Try adding the searchbar to a view before adding it to the navigation controller.

```
UIView *searchBarView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[searchBar bounds]];
[searchBarView addSubview:searchBar];
self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBarView;
```

Comment: I already tried that but it didn't work. All that does is add the button without animation but it's still invisible. I create the search bar programatically so there's no outlets to connect only the delegate which is assigned correctly because the delegate methods are all working.

Comment: @kyzer1978 i missed the part about it being in a navigationItem. I updated my answer

Comment: Thanks. I tried that as well with no luck. I don't think putting it in the navigation control is the problem because there's another search bar in my app on a different tableViewController that has the same problem but it's in the tableview header instead of the navigation controller.

Comment: @kyzer1978 can you create a test project and upload it somewhere?

Comment: I just figured it out. It had something to do with the background image I was using.  Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. The button is there but the titleColor is the same as it's background. What I did to fix it was searching for the cancel button subview of the search bar and set the button's title color to some different color. Be aware to setting this **after** the cancel button is shown, the view isn't there if before the cancel button is shown.
My code:

```
        [self.mySearchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
        if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 7.0) {
            for(id subview in [self.mySearchBar subviews])
            {
                if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
                    [self.cancelButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    [self.cancelButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

                }
            }
        } else {
            for(id subview in [[[self.mySearchBar subviews] objectAtIndex:0] subviews])
            {
                if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
                    [self.cancelButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    [self.cancelButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
                }
            }
        }
```

Also note that in iOS 7 the cancel button is buried in the search bar's first subview. Prior iOS 7 it is a direct subview of searchbar.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a bug,Please make sure the tint color is visible with your background color.[image]

Answer (score -1):

> _searchBar.backgroundImage = <#Some Color#>;
>   _searchBar.backgroundColor = <#Some Color#>; // Cancel Button Color.

Answer (score -1):

By going through above answers, I was unable to figure out the correct answer.
    As this is very old question, but if someone come across this issue and they using Storybaord, there is a option available in Storybaord (i.e click on UISearchbar , then go to Attribute Inspector and in Options look for "Shows Cancel Button") . Please refer the screenshot[image]